# online tool available to validate regex in firestore?

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There are tools available to validate the regex used in javascript / prolong etc but i am writing rules in google-cloud-firestore. I want some tool to check my regex.

please suggest.

Comment: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) not sufficient?

Comment: no, it didn't provide google-cloud-firestore

Comment: No information there about the flavour used?

Answer (score 1):

If you read my original answer.  Ignore it.

You can use the `matches` comparison.

> matches
>
> Performs a regular expression match, returns true if the whole
>   string matches the given regular expression. Uses Google RE2 syntax.

The full list of string validation rules available for Cloud Firestore are shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#string).

Comment: that's a run time check. For this I need to develop a demo app or something..
I want online tool to test.

Comment: In the RTDB, there's a simulator for checking the rules.  This doesn't exist for Cloud Firestore.  You can request it [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)